# Lyrics with timestamp for development

Tags: data-request, music

We are developing a mobile app to follow along songs and lectures with transcript.

Because we need to follow the audio with the transcript we decided to use [LRC format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)), specifically the Enhanced version. This should work fine in the final product, **but where can I find an example of this type of file?**

I don't mind the content of the audio. I need just a sample enhanced lrc file to develop the app and make a MVP version

Comment: check out webvtt; i don't know how to create .lrc but sounds similar to webvtt. you could create .lrc from .webvttt: https://github.com/brenopolanski/html5-video-webvtt-example

Comment: webvttt looks ok, but it does not support word stamp, **which we need**. If this wasn't required we could use regular srt files

Comment: i do not see word stamp on the wikipedia page for LRC format; what is that

Comment: Stamp are the time tags `[mm:ss.xx]` and `<mm:ss.xx>`. They represent the time that a word or phrase is relevant

Comment: vtt has timestampps like 00:00:00.500 --> 00:00:04.000 more here https://github.com/brenopolanski/html5-video-webvtt-example/blob/master/MIB2-subtitles-pt-BR.vtt

Comment: Again, vtt does have timestamps, but they cannot be applied to words, in this regard `LRC` is more efficient. WEBVTT is better to subtitle a video, LRC is better to subtitle audio (specially karaoke style like I need)

Comment: not again, you never said any of that in the first place. i'm not saying use webvtt in place of lrc, i said create lrc from webvtt. those timestamps most certainly are applied to words as they are spoken in video media so users can follow along. something like this https://github.com/Smile4ever/subconv

Comment: you maybe able to find something here but its not clear to me: https://www.audiocontentanalysis.org/data-sets/